# How to enable lightning component only for a particular page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, flexipages

If I implement flexipage:availableForRecordHome in component, the user will be able to add the component in the record page alone. Now I want the component to appear only in a particular page. For example the component should only be added to CASE page and ACCOUNT page and not any other pages. Is this possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, by using the Design file, you can restrict access to just certain objects. This in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm):

> ## `<sfdc:object>` and `<sfdc:objects>`
>
> Use these tag sets to restrict your component to one or more objects.

...

Example:

```
<design:component label="Hello World">
    <design:attribute name="subject" label="Subject" description="Name of the person you want to greet" />
    <design:attribute name="greeting" label="Greeting" />
    <sfdc:objects>
        <sfdc:object>Custom__c</sfdc:object>
        <sfdc:object>Opportunity</sfdc:object>
    </sfdc:objects>
</design:component>
```

Comment: I was literally like "I like this question, I'm going to wait for sfdcfox to answer it so I can learn this too." so... thanks :)

Comment: +1,Brilliant is this a new feature?

Comment: I read this feature few years back.. nd forgot.. glad sfdc fox answerd

Comment: @RedDevil It was introduced in [Winter '17](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lightning_design_file_object_restriction.htm), so three releases ago (not including Summer '18).